# How to completely remove firefox and reinstall in fedora

Tags: linux, firefox, fedora

I want to remove firefox completely in my fedora 17 as its having some issues after upgrading from firefox 12 to firefox 22.

I already have tried `yum remove firefox` and `yum install firefox` but it is not solving issues.

The issues are right click menu is not working in the browser. "Firebug" is not working.

How can i remove all physical backup files or firefox related files in fedora 17

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the package via the software manager as you did is all there is. You can check the files inside the package if you feel like, but there is no additional magic outside that file list. BUT: in addition you must remove your personal settings, otherwise those 'survive' the replacement of the package. Look for a hidden folder in your home directory: `.firefox` or `.mozilla` (note the leading dot).

Comment: thank you for the answer sir, ok i have find out .mozilla dir so i need to delete it first and then try to install it ?

Comment: That folder stores all your personal settings, preferences, extensions and other things connected to mozilla applications. If you delete it all your personal modifications (like the firebug plugin) are removed which probably is what you want. However you also remove all your settings too. Maybe rename it first to see if it helps :-)

Comment: ok, i already have exported all my bookmarks in .json so that i can restore it. other things are not much important. thanks anyway for the answer.